# How can I create a table of variable height in which every single cell contains an input field?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, postgresql

As I said in the title, I need to create a table in which every cell has a numeric input. So I created a component and I want to capture in the ts file what the user inserted in every cell (I also need to know in which cell he inserted the data too). In addition, the table should have a scalable number of rows(I need to populate the table with data from db, so please let me know if there is a way to precompile it)

Here I have added the html I tried even though it's not enough to do what I want to do.

```
<form #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(login.value)" novalidate>
<table class="rtable">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th *ngFor="let column of months">
            {{column}}
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let row of FigProfs">
        {{row.nome}}
        <td *ngFor="let column of mesi">
            <input type="number" #{{column}}_{{row}}="ngModel" required name="{{column}}_{{row}}" class="formControl" ngModel>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="btnsubmit" type="submit">GO</button>
```

This table has months in the heading and some characteristics on the left side. I need to let the user edit the cell of the table and I have to bring this information to my ts code, example:
"january/characteristic x -> data written from the user " ;
so I want to have in my ts all the data that I inserted down here (the heigth of the table is variable so I cannot insert form controls for the many inputs I have in the pic rn)

[image]

I know this code is probably completely wrong but I don't know how to do it in an easier way.
Thank you in advice for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should check out [DataTables](https://datatables.net)

Comment: Please post what you have tried, or at least some pseudo-code to represent it, including the Angular syntax you are thinking of using (e.g. *ngFor, [formGroup], etc). https://angular.io/start/start-forms might also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done. Thank you for adding some code. For reference, I really just used information from Angular's [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) below.

I did want to re-use some of your sample code, but unfortunately couldn't get it to adapt in a logical way. But you should be able to use the below to get it adapted as you need it.

My assumption is that you are using the Angular CLI to generate your components, and thus your .ts and .html are already referenced and created properly. In your **something.component.ts**, you will need to add something similar to:

```js
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//Create an interface for the data
interface testIntf {
  index: string, 
  fname: string, 
  lname: string, 
}

 
 ...skipping the existing stuff...

export class SomethingComponent implements OnInit {
    //Some sample data for headings
    headings = ["Index", "First name", "Surname"];
    
    //Some sample data for the form to be pre-filled. Note the use of the interface. Going forward you will likely import your data using Observables.
      dataArray: testIntf[] = [
    {"index": "1", "fname": "Test", "lname": "One"},
    {"index": "2", "fname": "Tester", "lname": "Two"},
    {"index": "3", "fname": "", "lname": ""},
    {"index": "4", "fname": "", "lname": ""},
]
    
    //Your form related stuff!!
    //Note where this matches in the html

   //Create an empty form
   dataForm = new FormGroup({});
    
    //Note that ngOnInit must be imported and implemented above
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.generateControls(this.dataArray);
  }

    //Add controls based on number of entries in array
    generateControls(x: testIntf[]) {
     var y = x.length
     for (let i = 0; i < y; i++){
       var z = x[i].index;
       this.dataForm.addControl("firstName"+z, new FormControl);
       this.dataForm.addControl("lastName"+z, new FormControl);
     }
   }
  
    //Getting your form data when submitted
    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.dataForm.value); //Push the form data into console.log of your browser
    }
    
}
```

And now in your **something.component.html**:

```html
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <table class="rtable">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of headings"> <!--Processs the "headings" array in the ts file-->
                {{column}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr *ngFor="let row of dataArray">
            <td>
                {{row.index}}
            </td>   
            <td>
                <input id="first-name{{row.index}}" type="text" formControlName="firstName{{row.index}}" value="{{row.fname}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="last-name{{row.index}}" type="text" formControlName="lastName{{row.index}}" value="{{row.lname}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



<p>Form Status: {{ dataForm.status }}</p> <!--Echo form data locally-->>
```

The information from your database can easily replace the "dataArray". Just update your headings, and add the necessary extra input fields to "dataForm".

Once you are comfortable with that, I would encourage you to look at Angular's Material for [tables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

**EDIT**
Going forward, should you want to add more fields, you would edit the following (I have used "telNo" as an example):

- Add extra fields to the form in **something.component.ts**:

```js
    generateControls(x: testIntf[]) {
     var y = x.length
     for (let i = 0; i < y; i++){
       var z = x[i].index;
       this.dataForm.addControl("firstName"+z, new FormControl);
       this.dataForm.addControl("lastName"+z, new FormControl);
       this.dataForm.addControl("telNo"+z, new FormControl);
     }
   }
```

- Add extra form field in your table in **something.component.html**:

```html
    <td>
        <input id="tel-no{{row.index}}" type="text" formControlName="telNo{{row.index}}" value="{{row.telno}}">
    </td>
```

- Obviously your dataArray will also need to be updated to have a "telno" field:

```js
    {"index": "1", "fname": "Test", "lname": "One", "telno": "1234587"},
```

And do not forget to update your interface:

```js
interface testIntf {
  index: string, 
  fname: string, 
  lname: string, 
  telno: string,
}
```

Comment: thank you bryan! you have been very helpful! i have only one problem; what can i do if i want to insert many datas in the table before to press the submit button? following your example i need to insert many firstnames and lastnames and i have to know the position in witch the user inserted it in the table, is there a way to do it? thank you again

Comment: I added an edit that will hopefully answer your question

Comment: ok brian thanks, i'm about to solve it, but what if i want to have in the function submit the datas of more than one row of the table? example :name:mark surname:ross then another  input, name: frank surname:black, than again name:jane, surname :brown and so on for a variable number of times. i have my table and i have to insert a numeric value in every field of it, sorry for my bad english anyways ;-D

Comment: i edited the question in order to be clearer

Comment: Ok. I think I better understand your need. I revised the code to use an interface, and it use ngOnInit() to create the form controls when based on the data in the array.

Comment: @Bryan, why not use a FormArray?

Comment: @Eliseo: :D In retrospect that's a great idea! But considering where we started, this helped the OP get used to form in Angular. And I am sure he will comfortably explore FormArray with the knowledge he has now gained.  think yours is a very good suggestion.